# Solrj server in EJB 3 container

Tags: solr, ejb-3.0, solrj

Using JBoss EAP 6.1 and Solr 4.5

How do people interact with Solr (via Solrj) in the EJB container?  Do most people create a managed bean wrapping the SolrServer implementation?  How many instances or singleton (queuing commits and so forth)?  Also contemplating using the embedded server which adds in thread-safety considerations.

Have some gone as far as a JCA adapter?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is using HibernateSearch in the JPA layer.

You will need to implement your own Solr Worker Backend, you can find an example here:  [HibernateSearchSolrWorkerBackend](https://github.com/avner-levy/hibernate_search_solr_integration/blob/master/src/main/java/example/hibernate_search_solr_integration_example/solr_adapter/HibernateSearchSolrWorkerBackend.java)

In your solr worker backend is where you will use SolrJ, and after annotate your entities with  [HibernateSearch annotation](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/search.html) it will interact automatically with solr after each transaction is commited. So all your indexes will be always up to date.

You can take a look at this entire example to have an idea on how to implement it  [hibernate_search_solr_integration](https://github.com/avner-levy/hibernate_search_solr_integration)

In the above project you will find a complete spring example. If you want to use just plane JPA objects you need to have something like this in your persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <persistence version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
     <persistence-unit name="espn-mediacatalog">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/your-datasourceDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>            


        <property name="hibernate.search.default.worker.backend" value="com.xxx.xxproject.jpa.solr.HibernateSearchSolrWorkerBackend" />         
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="org.hibernate.search.store.impl.RAMDirectoryProvider" />

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

cheers!

Comment: Great tip @delkant.  Totally forgot about Hibernate Search.  Will look at the Solr integration.  Thanks!